# Derivative through the integral of two variables function

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Problem: Let $h$ be a function in $C^1(\mathbb{R})$. Calculate the following derivative
$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\int_{0}^{t}h(s,x-c(t-s))ds.$$

My first attempt: I have searched for a way to solve it and find that we can solve it by Leibniz's integral theorem and then obtain that
$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\int_{0}^{t}h(s,x-c(t-s))ds = h(t,x) - \int_0^t\dfrac{d}{dx}h(s,x-c(t-s))ds.$$

My second attempt: On the other hand, I also try to find another natural way such following. $$\dfrac{d}{dt}\int_{0}^{t}h(s,x-c(t-s))ds = \dfrac{d}{dt}\left[H(t,x) - H(0,x-ct)\right]\\
= h(t,x) + c\dfrac{d}{dx}H(0,x-ct).$$
Now, I am stucking here. Anyone can show me how to continue or where I do wrong if there exists something wrong.

Comment: Hint. Write the integral as $H(t,t)$ where the first $t$ is the integration limit, and the second $t$ is the one inside the function $h(s,x-c(t-s))$. Then use
$\frac{d}{dt}H(t,t)=\partial_1H(t,t)+\partial_2H(t,t)$ which is a simple consequence of the chain rule applied to $t\mapsto (t,t)\mapsto H(t,t)$.

Comment: @KurtG. May you give me more information? This is the first time I have dealt with this kind of problem. So it makes me so confused.

Comment: Use chain rule on the function $t\mapsto (t,t)$ composed with $(x,y)\mapsto H(x,y)$ . It is simpler than you think. More information will probably just confuse you more. I don't even know where to begin unless you ask a very specific question.

Comment: Any opinion on my answer ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP does not respond.

Comment: @KurtG. Sorry. I have just checked the reply because I have some busy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With slightly better notation than in the comments, write
$$
H(t_1,t_2)=\int_0^{t_1}h\Big(s,x-c(t_2-s)\Big)\,ds
$$
and use chain rule on $t\mapsto (t,t)$ composed with $H$. This gives
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}H(t,t)&=\partial_1 H(t,t)+\partial_2 H(t,t)\\
&=h(t,x)+\frac{\partial}{\partial t_2}\Bigg|_{t_2=t}\int_0^th\Big(s,x-c(t_2-s)\Big)\,ds\\
&=h(t,x)-c\int_0^t\partial_2\,h\Big(s,x-c(t-s)\Big)\,ds\,.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you a lot. It is more clear to me now. I have already seen the difference between the one variable case and the multivariable case.